# Module imports, but doesn't have any attributes

Tags: python

I am trying to import a Python module (fiasco). I cloned it from GitHub and everything appeared to be working fine. Importing it works, but when I try to type, for example `iron = fiasco.Element('iron', [1e4, 1e6, 1e8]*u.K)`, I get the error `module 'fiasco' has no attribute 'Element'`. I am using Spyder's iPython console. This also fails if I start iPython from the terminal, but works if I start python3 from the terminal.

I had done this on two different computers - on one, it worked at first, but started giving me the same error after I restarted the kernel. On the other, it never worked at all.

If it helps: after importing, I tried typing `fiasco`. When I did this on the computer where it originally worked, the output was `<module 'fiasco' from '/Users/shirman/fiasco/fiasco/__init__.py'>`. Now, and on the computer it never worked on, it just says `<module 'fiasco' (namespace)>`. So maybe this has something to do with paths?

Addition: `sys.path` points to `/Users/shirman`, and several paths within `/Users/shirman/anaconda3`. The fiasco folder is in `/Users/shirman`.

Comment: The typical way to use a 3rd party module is to install it with a package manager, such as pip or conda, rather than to clone the source code from GitHub.

Comment: Yes, your `sys.path` will be pointing to a different directory, perhaps to `/Users/shirman`.

Comment: Did you possibly create another source file called `fiasco.py`?

Comment: There already was a ```fiasco.py``` file there, don't think I created anything additional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inadvertently created a namespace package due to your `sys.path` setting. Namespace packages are directories without an `__init__.py` in the Python search path and allow loading of submodules or -packages from different paths (e.g. `path1/foo/a.py` and `path2/foo/b.py` can be imported as `foo.a` and `foo.b`).

The problem is that `import fiasco` finds `/Users/shirman/fiasco` first and imports it as a namespace package. If you set sys.path such that `/Users/shirman/fiasco` comes before `/Users/shirman`, the importer finds the actual package `/Users/shirman/fiasco/fiasco` first.

Namespace packages are a Python 3.3 feature, so either the other machine had a different `sys.path` setting, a really old Python 3 installation, or you were using Python 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added ```/Users/shirman/fiasco``` to ```$PYTHONPATH``` and looks like it works now.